# Requirejs loading racing issue in MVC .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm using requirejs with knockout on .NET 5 MVC framework this is how I lay out my application.

This is my _Layout.cshtml which is pretty normal to

```
<head></head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
       // body stuff
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("Constants", "Configuration")"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/vendors/requirejs/require.js" data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/main")"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
```

And then each page that requires to use knockoutjs I do something like this.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        require(['app', 'viewmodels/search/search'], function (app, contentModule) {
            app.render(contentModule);
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is my app.js to activate knockoutjs

```
define('app', ['require'], function (localRequire) {

    var app = {
        render: function(module) {
            localRequire(['knockout', 'zepto'], function(ko, $) {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    ko.cleanNode($('.wrapper')[0]);
                    ko.applyBindings(module, $('.wrapper')[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };

    return app;

});
```

Everything seems fine, however, sometimes I get this error that requirejs cannot load knockout and zepto which I assume it's something to do with some racing condition. This is not happening every time.

```
GET http://localhost:91/Scripts/app/knockout.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1895
Uncaught Error: Script error for: knockout
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:166
GET http://localhost:91/Scripts/app/zepto.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1895
Uncaught Error: Script error for: zepto
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call require() inside your main script (the script specified in data-main attribute).

The main script is called asynchronously so the require() function in your page may be called before RequireJS is configured.

See this http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main